# How to get a list of only the most recent data belonging an Entity from a table with multiple data belonging the same Entity using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have a table called TicketHistory in which TicketId is a ForeignKey and I store records of update operations that are performed on ticket properties such as 'Status', 'Assignee', 'Priority', 'UpdateDate' etc. as my table data.
So there is multiple rows with same TicketId value in the table.

What I am trying to do is writing Linq to fetch the List of history records belong to certain tickets that were at least once their Status updated as lets say "X". But as I said same update operation might have been performed on the same ticket multiple times and I want to retrieve only the latest one. So Basically only one record belong to a certain ticket (I am providing ticket Id(s)) which is the one that the ticket's status was updated as X last time.

I am using EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.4 and the Linq I wrote is as in below:

```cs
var histories = await _context.TicketHistories
    .Include(i => i.Ticket).ThenInclude(t => t.Status)
    .Include(n => n.Ticket).ThenInclude(h => h.Priority)
    .Where(w => ticketIds.Any(a => a == w.TicketId) &&
                w.Status.TicketStatusCode == "X" &&
                w.Active &&
                !w.Deleted)
    .GroupBy(g => g.TicketId)
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Max(m => m.Created))
    .Select(s => s.FirstOrDefault())
    .ToListAsync();
```

Well, when I run the code above I get some error message as in title: "Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid."

Can you guys please help me to correct my linq or at least show me the way.

Comment: Looks like `Status` and/or `Priority` are no navigation properties. Please show the class model. Also it's usually better to give the exact exception message rather than a paraphrase.

Comment: You are right! Priority is non-navigation property of TicketHistory so it was mistake to include it. The answer from @Svyatoslav Danyliv solved my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is known EF Core limitation, you cannot get items after grouping. Only `Key` and aggregation result is supported. Note that starting from EF Core 6, your query will work.

You can use the following workaround, which mimics EF Core 6 query translation:

```cs
var dataQuery = _context.TicketHistories
    .Include(i => i.Ticket).ThenInclude(t => t.Status)
    .Include(n => n.Ticket)
    .Where(w => ticketIds.Contains(w.TicketId) &&
                w.Status.TicketStatusCode == "X" &&
                w.Active &&
                !w.Deleted);
var query = 
    from key in dataQuery.Select(d => new { d.TicketId }).Distinct()
    from d in dataQuery.Where(d => d.TicketId == key.TicketId)
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.Created)
        .Take(1)
    select d; 

var histories = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Comment: You know this is duplicate, right? Even for couple of your own answers.

Comment: It is so hard to find them or they are a little bit outdated, anyway I can  remove answer.

Comment: You are not forced to - just a note. You may create list with bookmarks of your common problem answers, and vote to close as duplicate.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I still have the same error message when the last line of your code executed `code`var histories = await query.ToListAsync();`code`

Comment: Show your model. Probably you have put into `Include` non-navigation property.

Comment: Actually you are right. Priority is a non-navigation property in TicketHistory Entity. So, it can't be included to the query. Many thanks for your help :)